# Faster way to display scientific data than a picture box in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I am using VB.net (VS2019) to display data coming in from a instrument (mass spectrometer). I am trying to stream, process and display 2048 data points in 100ms intervals. Drawing 2000 odd lines in a picturebox is by far the biggest bottle neck. What would be the alternative?

Comment: I've never used it in that specific scenario but, if you want to display a chart, the `Chart` control seems the obvious choice.

Comment: Can a person, looking at your screen, process 2048 data points at the same time?

Comment: On MS spectra you look for patterns. Most of the data is noise and every now and again one mass will spike. That's the information people are interested in.